# Pass a primitive as a generic parameter in order to use it as an object key

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In my object, I have two properties, one of which is hardcoded and the second one has to be dynamic. How can I pass the desired key name in generic type so that it yields a type with that key?

Example:

```
interface Pagination<key, Content> {
  pagination: {
      total: number;
      page: number;
  },
  `${key}`: Content[];
}

// expected behavior
type ProductData = Pagination<'products', Product>;
const productResponse: ProductData = {
  pagination: {...},
  products: [...],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `Pagination` to a `type` and [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) it with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) containing only a single key. The generic type `Key` also needs a constraint which can either be `string`, `number` or `symbol` or a union of those.

```
type Pagination<Key extends string, Content> = {
  pagination: {
      total: number;
      page: number;
  },
} & {
  [K in Key]: Content[];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIAKcD2ATAVxSgG8BfUUKATwAcNMkBzSJKMHCAHgGkZr0MAB6wIeAM7pxUOJCYAadAGFOoqAD50AXnQlQ6dLWat2nAFy79B61BxQkAGwsQCAWwBG8ANxXrh5jDObp5wPiAGZPKgZOgAZJbh6ADaPOiQ6HzUALoWKtAw0ElZYRQgoAD05YJC9MQweOieABZIAG4ccFR0DLiExAAibEjaWMYQbBzcAOS0vURQ4lOK2Pjz6mGgKJzShnPEAEow4rTbgVh7UIP2I3qJRizjphAWt34G92cADFGJfrb2TnQnyskSss1WxHEFiKPzIQA)

Comment: @tobia-s, oh, I didn't think about extending types! I thought that there's a possibility to interpolate key in the interfaces or something like this. Thank you, I will be using this technique!